Plt.scatter unwanted normalization of colorbar
I have a dataframe (cumulative_diff_df) containing values for pixels in space:
          X coordinate  Y coordinate  Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct  \
0         2669756.6     1259017.6                             904.994102   
1         2669756.6     1259017.8                             876.358333   
2         2669756.6     1259034.8                            1082.645719   
3         2669756.6     1259035.0                            1039.702085   
4         2669756.6     1259035.4                            1442.291473   
...             ...           ...                                    ...   
69887     2669803.6     1259002.8                            1483.007732   
69888     2669803.6     1259003.2                             547.435019   
69889     2669803.6     1259003.4                             624.091325   
69890     2669803.6     1259003.6                             470.575287   
69891     2669803.6     1259004.8                             496.540173   

       Cumulative Absolute Difference Diffuse  
0                                   84.099907  
1                                   85.462752  
2                                  143.034784  
3                                   98.758423  
4                                  153.982973  
...                                       ...  
69887                              179.913676  
69888                               74.068084  
69889                              120.342678  
69890                               77.374445  
69891                              106.994752  

[69892 rows x 4 columns]

Now I want to plot their difference in direct and indirect irradiance in two separate subplots using this code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib_scalebar.scalebar import ScaleBar

# Get the current color limits
direct_min = cumulative_diff_df['Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct'].min()
print(direct_min)
direct_max = cumulative_diff_df['Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct'].max()
print(direct_max)

# First subplot for direct irradiance
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.scatter(cumulative_diff_df['X coordinate'], cumulative_diff_df['Y coordinate'], s=100, c=cumulative_diff_df['Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct'],cmap='YlGnBu_r',vmin=direct_min, vmax=direct_max)
plt.scatter(top_10_direct_pixels['X coordinate'], top_10_direct_pixels['Y coordinate'], color='red', marker='x', s=100, label='Top 10 Direct pixels')
plt.title('Daily Difference Direct Irradiance', fontsize=13)
cbar = plt.colorbar(label='Direct Irradiance difference [$Wh/m^2$]', norm=None)


# Set the color limits for the color bar
cbar.set_clim(vmin=direct_min, vmax=direct_max)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)  # Increase the size of colorbar ticks and labeling
cbar.set_label('Direct Irradiance difference [$Wh/m^2$]', fontsize=15)
# Omit X and Y axis labels
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
scale=1
# Add scale bar
scalebar = ScaleBar(scale, location='lower right')  # Adjust location as needed
plt.gca().add_artist(scalebar)
plt.legend()

Everything works as expected but the colorbar is normalized between 0 and 1, instead of the difference values as you see within the dataframe.
I've already tried clim for the colorbar and vmin, vmax for the data but nothing seems to work.
Does anybody know what's wrong here?
Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Please only include a minimal reproducible example and also give easy access to your data or a subset of it, so that everyone can reproduce the problem and help you.

You are creating two scatter plots on the same subplot.  The colorbar seems to get the bar for the second scatter plot.  You can try to save the result of the firstscatter1 = plt.scatter(cumulative_diff_df ....) and use it as the first parameter in plt.colorbar(scatter1, ...). You could also remove nomr=None from that call, as it doesn't help anything.

@JohanC Thank you so much! Such a simple mistake but I didn't notice it!

Thanks to the answer of @JohanC I could solve it as follows:
# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
# Get the current color limits
direct_min = cumulative_diff_df['Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct'].min()
print(direct_min)
direct_max = cumulative_diff_df['Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct'].max()
print(direct_max)

# First subplot for direct irradiance
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
l1= plt.scatter(cumulative_diff_df['X coordinate'], cumulative_diff_df['Y coordinate'], s=pixel_size, c=cumulative_diff_df['Cumulative Absolute Difference Direct'],cmap='YlGnBu_r',vmin=direct_min, vmax=direct_max)
plt.scatter(top_10_direct_pixels['X coordinate'], top_10_direct_pixels['Y coordinate'], color='red', marker='x', s=100, label='Top 10 Direct pixels')
plt.title('Daily Difference Direct Irradiance', fontsize=13)
cbar = plt.colorbar(l1,label='Direct Irradiance difference [$Wh/m^2$]')


You should call plt.scatter(cumulative_diff_df ...) only once. It's best to remove the second call, to make things less confusing.
